Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении? (2)
Помогите расставить запятые в предложении.
А(,) бывало(,) представлял, как летит.

"А бывало, помню (ему еще было 3 года), бывало, барыня посадит его на колена к себе и начнет играть на фортепьянах что-нибудь жалкое." Лермонтов.

Чаще "а бывало", чем "а, бывало", - но скорее всего и так и так можно.

Корректно: А бывало, представлял, как летит.
Вводное слово "бывало" стоит после союза а и не отделяется от него   запятой, т. к. изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, нарушается структура предложения.
Ср: А представлял, как летит.
Подробнее об обособлении вводных слов после союза см. в Справочнике по русскому языку: Орфография и пунктуация. Розенталь Д.Э.
Вводные слова и словосочетания, пункт 5

Серж: «Вводное слово "бывало" стоит перед союзом а…» === Не перед. После.

@Слава, спасибо за поправку.

Серж, у Вас «перед» в ответе есть ещё и в последнем абзаце. Его тоже надо поправить.

@Серж Ещё: запятая перед "как" (в одном случае она есть, в другом — нет) и точка после фамилии Розенталь.

@РиммаМихайлова, а точка-то есть.

@Серж: «РиммаМихайлова, а точка-то есть». === Наверное, её-то и не должно было бы быть?

@Слава,точка как раз нужна. См. один из ответов Грамоты ру.нужно ли ставить две точки в конце предложения в таком случае: По этому вопросу обращаться к Иванову И.И.. Нужно ли после инициалов в конце предложения ставить вторую точку?
ОТВЕТ
Нет, вторая точка не ставится. Правильно: к Иванову И. И.

@Серж: «Слава, точка как раз нужна».  === Серж, Вы не поняли, о какой точке шла речь. До последней (пятой) правки, сделанной Риммой, Ваш ответ включал и точку после фамилии «Розенталь» вот в этом фрагменте: Орфография и пунктуация. Розенталь. Д.Э.  Римма эту точку, не  дождавшись Вашей правки, решила сама убрать.
